# CI/CD of Database in multiple instance - Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have written a step to deploy database build in respective database. But at a time, i am able to deploy one database ie one step for one db. is it possible to deploy same db build in multiple db at a step in relase?

Comment: I am totally new to this. Please help me to understand this scenario

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to deploy same db build in multiple db at a step in relase?

AFAIK, there is no build-in task to do it. But you could create a powershell/batch script that loops runs the sqlpackage.exe to deploy DAC to multiple db at a step in relase:

You could check the similar thread [Deployment to several databases using SQL Server Data Tools and Team foundation Server](https://www.sqlshack.com/deployment-several-databases-using-sql-server-data-tools-team-foundation-server/) for some details.

Besides, there are many extensions in Marketplace can do it, so choose some of them that meet your requirement:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=sql&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&visibilityQuery=all&sortBy=Relevance

Hope this helps.